# ios 11 color of the app (uinavigation)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar, uinavigationcontroller

Am using this color for the UINavigationController and some of other views

`[UIColor colorWithRed:0.137 green:0.137 blue:0.145 alpha:1.00]`

but there is a strange behaviour with iOS 11 when I run the application sometimes the color is correct (dark) and sometimes the color be in light mode a lighter than the  original color

Comment: Does the color appear lighter on `UINavigationBars`? If so, make sure that they're opaque.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

`[UIColor colorWithRed:0.137 green:0.137 blue:0.145 alpha:1.00]`

with

```
[UIColor colorWithRed:137.0/255.0 green:137.0/255.0 blue:145.0/255.0 alpha:1.00]
```